# Regex splitting punctuation from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

I want to split punctuation in a python string using white spaces with regex (`re.sub()` or `re.findall()`). So `"I like dog, and I like cat."` should become `"I like dog , and I like cat . "`

I have a string of punctuation (python `string.punctuation = "!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~"`) that I want to replace, but I also have a list of specific abbreviations I don't want to replace (say  `list1 = ["e.g." , "Miss."]`. AND I don't want to replace multiple punctuation (any two punctuation right next to each other, like `...` or `,"`) or any apostrophes like `I'm, you're, he's, we're`.

So say I have `list1 = ["e.g." , "Miss."]` and `string.punctuation = "!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~"`. Given a string `"I'm a cat, you're a dog, e.g. a cat... really?, non-dog!!"`, it should become `"I'm a cat , you're a dog , e.g. a cat ... really ?, non-dog !! "`

Is there a regex that can split a punctuation from a string except for my list of  specific abbreviations and multiple punctuation and apostrophes?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: provide a more testable, extended input string which covers all the conditions. Then, post the expected result

Comment: To preprocess a text body for classification purpose.

Comment: Why a single regex when it can be done much easier and more flexible with some code? I imagine a regex to add *all* spaces, followed by processing a list of exceptions. It's almost the canonical "let's use a regex – and then you have *two* problems".

Comment: With some code is fine too, I just want to find a solution of this, I have been using regex and stuck. Do you have some sample code that I could follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general algorithm is to process the input string from start to finish, scan if the next 'word' is in the exception list (if so, skip it) or is a punctuation character (if so, add spaces around).

That leads to the following function:

```
def preprocess(string, punctuation, exceptions):
    result = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(string):
        foundException = False
        if i == 0 or not(string[i-1].isalpha()):
            for e in exceptions:
                if string[i:].lower().startswith(e.lower()) and (i+len(e) == len(string) or not(string[i+len(e)].isalpha())):
                    result += string[i:i+len(e)]
                    i += len(e)
                    foundException = True
                    break
        if not(foundException):
            if string[i] in punctuation:
                result += ' '
                while i < len(string) and string[i] in punctuation:
                    result += string[i]
                    i += 1
                result += ' '
            else:
                result += string[i]
                i += 1

    return result.replace('  ', ' ')
```

When run in a test frame

```
examples = """
I like dog, and I like cat.
I'm a cat, you're a dog, e.g. a cat... really?, non-dog!!
"""

for line in examples.split('\n'):
    result = preprocess (line, "!\"#$%&'()*+,\\-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~", ["I'm", "you're", "e.g.", "he's", "we're", "Miss."])
    print (result)
```

you get the expected result for the first sentence

```
I like dog , and I like cat .
```

but the second sentence splits up `non-dog`:

```
I'm a cat , you're a dog , e.g. a cat ... really ?, non - dog !!
```

which suggests your specifications are inexact (unless `non-dog` would be in the exception list; then it behaves as expected).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. But one thing is I realized your solution only works on abbrevs like `e.g.`, but  not abbrevs like `Mr.`, even when I put `Mr.` in my exception list it still does not work. Namely `Mr.` still got separated as `Mr . `. Do you have any suggestion how to quick fix that?

Comment: @Davvvvad: you're right, it sounds as if that should have worked. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Davvvvad: I just added `"Mr."` to the exception list and it worked as intended. No other changes; I copied my exact code. `"Mr. I like dog, Mr. and I like Mr."` processes to the expected `Mr. I like dog , Mr. and I like Mr.`

Comment: You are right, I made change in your code. My bad. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex pattern like `[\.\,\:\;\?\(\)]` to find a list of matches of all punctuation in a string. Then loop each match replacing it with itself with a space appended to it.

Example:

```
data = "this is, the data."

myre = re.compile(r"[\.\,\:\;\?\(\)]")
matches = myre.findall(data)

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {

    data.replace(matches[i], " "+matches[i])

}
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not solve the problem with some specific pattern that I don't want to replace.

Comment: @Davvvvad can you not dynamically build the regex only with the punctuation you would like to search for?